# Natural acoustic modes of a open-open converging or diverging duct

Tags: acoustics, frequency

The fundamental frequencies of air columns depend on the length of the column, the speed of sound and the boundary conditions. For a straight duct the natural modes are

$f = \frac{n ~c_{sound}}{2L}$.

I am interested in finding the dependence of the same on geometry of the duct. How will the fundamental modes change when air flows through a converging or diverging duct whose both ends are open to the atmosphere.

The solution for frequency might depend on how the area varies (linear, quadratic, exponential) as a function of $x$. I would like to know a first order approximation with some physical reasoning as to whether the frequency will increase or decrease when compared with a straight duct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since this question is very well covered in literature, I will provide the first steps and you can do the discussion by yourself.

Usually, the first approximation is planar wave in a duct of varying cross section area $S = S(x)$. The modified wave equation for such a case is called the Webster equation:

$$
\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial (\ln S)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}  = \frac{1}{c_0^2}\frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial t^2}
$$

Consequent steps are straightforward:

- specify S(x)
- solve for $p(x,t)=X(x)T(t)=X(x)e^{i\omega t}$
- get the modes

Comment: Hi Victor, Thank you for the input. I found a similar equation in Tim Lieuwen's "Unsteady Combustor Physics"

Comment: Hi Victor, Thank you for the input. I found a similar equation in Tim Lieuwen's "Unsteady Combustor Physics" (Ch. 6 Aside 6.1). The wave equation suggested is similar to yours but the density change along the duct is also included.
$$
\frac{\partial^2 p'}{\partial x^2} + \frac{d\ln(A(x)/\rho_0(x))}{dx}\frac{\partial p'}{\partial x}  = \frac{1}{c_0^2}\frac{\partial^2 p'}{\partial t^2} $$